# Is it possible to pass post data to the form (prefill form with data)?

Tags: forms, post

For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask there we have form id="post-form" which has method="post", is it possible somehow open this form and have lets say Name input (display-name) with my name prefilled on load?

Comment: If you just want to set default values in some input components that live on a form, you could just add attributes to the request for the values that you want to set and use your web framework or JavaScript to access these off the request and set the attribute values as the default values of the inputs. Is this what you are trying to achieve or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this many ways, with Javascript by setting the input's text, or you can do it server-side with PHP by echoing `"value=\"$name\""` for the `value` attribute of the input.

Comment: No no, i mean without possibility modify code in form i'm submiting to... i can't do any changes on stackoverflow side :) but i want have a link in my application which goes to this form and my name is allready prefiled...